# Dojo 2.0 Canned Themes available?

Tags: dojo

I always like the themes found here: http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/themePreviewer/demo.html

Do those still work with Dojo 2.0 (Dojo.io)? 
Or are there new or other pre-designed themes available for Dojo 2.0?

I've seen the doc on how to theme and create themes (https://dojo.io/tutorials/007_theming/) but want to know if there are pre-existing themes.

Comment: see this https://github.com/dojo/themes

Comment: I've looked there, but looks like will take me a few hours to try everything.  I kind of step in and out of Javascript and NodeJS every few months.  In the old site, they had demos that actually ran, right there on the website, and four themes: claro, tundra, soria, nihilo.  I don't see any such themes or names of themes in that project.

Comment: I tried the Discord forum for Dojo - and they referred me here: https://github.com/dojo/examples/tree/master/custom-element-showcase and said one theme is available, haven't had time to check it out yet; when I do, I can put in as answer.

Comment: And this one: https://dojo.github.io/examples/widget-showcase/

Comment: great , seems still under dev (themes)